# How to call a servlet from html and the servlet call the jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create a  Link in index.html whitch call the servlet and it call a jsp to be displayed, but I'm getting error 404 and already tried many 'solves' (which I found in Internet).

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about to send redirect to JSP URL from your servlet as a response?